# Insert counts at specific positions using bash (sed or awk?)

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, pacman-package-manager

I have a file (`mirrorlist.pacnew`) containing mirrors like this:

```
prakhar@inS4n3 ~ $ cat /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.pacnew 
...
## Worldwide
#Server = https://dgix.ru/mirrors/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.rackspace.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Australia
#Server = http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
...
```

I am supposed to choose mirrors and uncomment those. However, a tool `rankmirrors` determines the best mirrors for me, so I use `sed` to **uncomment all of them**.

```
prakhar@inS4n3 ~ $ cat /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.pacnew | sed -r 's/^#([^#]+)/#\1\n\1/'
...
## Worldwide
#Server = https://dgix.ru/mirrors/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = https://dgix.ru/mirrors/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#Server = http://mirror.rackspace.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.rackspace.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Australia
#Server = http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
...
```

**I am keeping the commented lines because rankmirrors prints them and I can keep track of progress (it doesn't print un-commented lines it is processing).**

However, I would like `sed` or `awk` to print **server count and total count** in each line as well.

Specifically:

1. Uncomment lines as I gave an example above.
2. Print the index of the current **#Server** index (not the actual line number, as the file contains county names, generic comments) from the original file.

The final output will look somewhat like this:

```
#22/247 Server = http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
```

[Here](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/?country=all&protocol=http&ip_version=4)'s a copy of the full file.

EDIT:

I have made some progress myself, and I added my work as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31453509/3887393), as it achieves the above, but not optimally.

Comment: sed is not able to count. awk is your friend. But there is another problem: You want to print how many Servers are available in total. That is a problem when using a stream logic as given by sed and awk. It is possible though.

Comment: If 247 is the total number of #Server = http... lines, you can get that first with grep -n "^#Server = http"

Comment: @ikrabbe I made an attempt using `sed` (I added an answer below). Can you please comment on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the same file twice to awk. First pass, get count. Second pass, substitute.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
         if( /^#Server *=/)count++;
         next;
     }
     /#Server *=/{
         sub(/^#*/,"");
         print "#" ++i "/" count " " $0;
    }
    1' serverlist serverlist
```

Gives:

```
## Worldwide
#1/3 Server = https://dgix.ru/mirrors/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = https://dgix.ru/mirrors/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#2/3 Server = http://mirror.rackspace.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.rackspace.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Australia
#3/3 Server = http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
```

Comment: Can you tell me how `Server = http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch` and the `## Australia` lines are printed? There is only one `print` statement

Comment: ^^ The `1` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` and `grep` only:

```
prakhar@inS4n3 ~ $ COUNT=$(grep -c "Server" /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.pacnew); cat /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.pacnew | sed -r 's/^#([^#]+)/\1/;tx;d;:x'| sed = | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | sed -r 's/([0-9]+?)\sServer\s=\s(.*)/#\1 \/ '$COUNT' Trying \2\nServer = \2/'
...
#241 / 247 Trying http://mirrors.rutgers.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirrors.rutgers.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#242 / 247 Trying http://mirror.umd.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.umd.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#243 / 247 Trying http://mirror.vtti.vt.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirror.vtti.vt.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
#244 / 247 Trying http://mirrors.xmission.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
...
```

**TODO**:

1. I'm pretty sure this is non-optimal.
2. Difficult to read
3. Removes generic comments (*#Worldwide*)

**EDIT**: To handle generic comments:

```
user@host $ RANDOM_CHARACTER='@'
user@host $ sed ':b;N; $!bb; s|\n|'"$RANDOM_CHARACTER"'|g;s/#Server/#\nServer/g' /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.pacnew | \
    sed '2,$=' | \
    sed -r '/^[0-9]*$/{s|(.*)|echo "$((\1-1))/'$COUNT' "|e; N; s|\n([^'"$RANDOM_CHARACTER"']*)|\1'"$RANDOM_CHARACTER"'\1|}' | \
    sed ':b;N; $!bb;s|\n||g;s|'"$RANDOM_CHARACTER"'|\n|g'
```

Choose random character based on file contents - any character, that is not present in file & not used as delimiter for sed command.

Comment: `cat file | grep` is [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). Use `grep pattern file`

Comment: `cat | sed` is like UUOC too...
On another note, you should change `grep -c` pattern to a more restricted/narrow pattern, like `^#Server`

Comment: To avoid removal of generic comments, you could replace `\n` in the input with some other character (say, `@`) & `#Server` by `#\nServer`, so that all the 'lines' would start with Sever. Then pass it to `sed =` & then remove newlines & finally, replace all `@` by `\n` again.

Comment: @anishsane Yeah. That's a nice idea. However, complexity is still O(n^6) (vs awk's O(n^2). That would be a bigger issue.

Comment: No, it's still `O(N^2)` Only 2 passes of the file - once for grep, once for sed pipeline.

Comment: @anishsane Wouldn't the `sed` pipeline go through the file 5 times (in memory)?

Comment: I am using sed to convert `\n` to `@` & vice versa. But it should really be done using `tr` (because that's what `tr` is for.). `tr` stands for translate character. & it doesn't increase `O()` level, because it's a pipeline & thus happens in parallel. I used `sed` instead of `tr` only because you started your answer with, `sed and grep only:` :D